# Rhino3D will not start on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, rhino3d

I attempted to start [Rhino](http://www.rhino3d.com/) on Windows Server 2008 R2 and it starts the process but does not start up. I did install it on my Windows 7 laptop alright, but the first thing it did on that was start the program and start setting up the toolbars

On Windows Server 2008 R2 it starts the process in the task manager but nothing comes up ... has anyone ever experienced this before?

Comment: try asking at http://discourse.mcneel.com/

Comment: or email support@mcneel.com . They are really helpfull

Comment: they seemed stumped .. that is why I asked randomly here... Is there something odd in Windows Server that would stop windows from coming up?

Comment: We're not quite stumped. It's just that this problem is extremely rare, and none of the diagnostic tools we've got embedded in Rhino help us figure out the solution. Rhino dies so soon after startup, we don't even get a glimmer of what the problem is.